# Make a column out of values of a nested list

Tags: python, pandas

I'm getting this JSON string:

```
[{'open': 13.739999771118164, 'high': 13.739999771118164, 'low': 13.380000114440918, 'close': 13.460000038146973, 'time': {'day': 6, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 13.260000228881836, 'high': 13.770000457763672, 'low': 13.1899995803833, 'close': 13.739999771118164, 'time': {'day': 7, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 13.630000114440918, 'high': 13.850000381469727, 'low': 13.4399995803833, 'close': 13.529999732971191, 'time': {'day': 8, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 13.510000228881836, 'high': 13.59000015258789, 'low': 13.279999732971191, 'close': 13.279999732971191, 'time': {'day': 9, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 13, 'high': 13.210000038146973, 'low': 12.630000114440918, 'close': 12.75, 'time': {'day': 10, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 12.300000190734863, 'high': 12.380000114440918, 'low': 
11.739999771118164, 'close': 11.8100004196167, 'time': {'day': 13, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.989999771118164, 'high': 12.420000076293945, 'low': 11.90999984741211, 'close': 12.199999809265137, 'time': {'day': 14, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 12.220000267028809, 'high': 12.420000076293945, 'low': 12, 'close': 12.270000457763672, 'time': {'day': 15, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.800000190734863, 'high': 11.90999984741211, 'low': 11.119999885559082, 'close': 11.25, 'time': {'day': 16, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.239999771118164, 'high': 11.4399995803833, 'low': 10.899999618530273, 'close': 11.229999542236328, 'time': {'day': 17, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.550000190734863, 'high': 11.65999984741211, 'low': 11.350000381469727, 'close': 11.460000038146973, 'time': {'day': 21, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.260000228881836, 'high': 11.680000305175781, 'low': 11.210000038146973, 'close': 11.479999542236328, 'time': {'day': 22, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.5, 'high': 11.579999923706055, 'low': 11.25, 'close': 11.5600004196167, 'time': {'day': 23, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.649999618530273, 'high': 12.119999885559082, 'low': 11.569999694824219, 'close': 12.010000228881836, 'time': {'day': 24, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 12.119999885559082, 'high': 12.180000305175781, 'low': 11.899999618530273, 'close': 12.039999961853027, 'time': {'day': 27, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 12.140000343322754, 'high': 12.4399995803833, 'low': 11.800000190734863, 'close': 11.8100004196167, 'time': {'day': 28, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.739999771118164, 'high': 11.760000228881836, 'low': 11.380000114440918, 'close': 11.520000457763672, 'time': {'day': 29, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.239999771118164, 'high': 11.359999656677246, 'low': 10.930000305175781, 'close': 11.130000114440918, 'time': {'day': 30, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}}, {'open': 11.100000381469727, 'high': 11.5, 'low': 10.989999771118164, 'close': 11.319999694824219, 'time': {'day': 1, 'month': 7, 'year': 2022}}]
```

I'm converting it to pandas dataframe the following way:

```
candleData = pd.DataFrame(json.loads(request.GET.get('candleData')), columns=['open','high','low','close','time'])
```

Getting this results:

```
     open   high    low  close                                   time
0   13.74  13.74  13.38  13.46   {'day': 6, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
1   13.26  13.77  13.19  13.74   {'day': 7, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
2   13.63  13.85  13.44  13.53   {'day': 8, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
3   13.51  13.59  13.28  13.28   {'day': 9, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
4   13.00  13.21  12.63  12.75  {'day': 10, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
5   12.30  12.38  11.74  11.81  {'day': 13, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
6   11.99  12.42  11.91  12.20  {'day': 14, 'month': 6, 'year': 2022}
...
```

Now, what I want to do and I don't know how is making the column time out of its nested list making it a real date like this:

```
     open   high    low  close       time
0   13.74  13.74  13.38  13.46   6-6-2022
1   13.26  13.77  13.19  13.74   7-6-2022
2   13.63  13.85  13.44  13.53   8-6-2022
3   13.51  13.59  13.28  13.28   9-6-2022
4   13.00  13.21  12.63  12.75  10-6-2022
5   12.30  12.38  11.74  11.81  13-6-2022
6   11.99  12.42  11.91  12.20  14-6-2022
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see two options (see second part for the format).

Convert the time Series to DataFrame with [`pandas.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html), then to datetime with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html):

```
candleData['time'] = pd.to_datetime(pd.json_normalize(candleData['time']))
```

Or, `apply` to convert to [`pandas.Timestamp`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.html), expanding the dictionary as parameters:

```
candleData['time'] = candleData['time'].apply(lambda x: pd.Timestamp(**x))
```

*NB. in both cases it is important to have **day / month / years** as dictionary keys!*

output:

```
     open   high    low  close       time
0   13.74  13.74  13.38  13.46 2022-06-06
1   13.26  13.77  13.19  13.74 2022-06-07
2   13.63  13.85  13.44  13.53 2022-06-08
3   13.51  13.59  13.28  13.28 2022-06-09
4   13.00  13.21  12.63  12.75 2022-06-10
5   12.30  12.38  11.74  11.81 2022-06-13
6   11.99  12.42  11.91  12.20 2022-06-14
7   12.22  12.42  12.00  12.27 2022-06-15
8   11.80  11.91  11.12  11.25 2022-06-16
9   11.24  11.44  10.90  11.23 2022-06-17
10  11.55  11.66  11.35  11.46 2022-06-21
11  11.26  11.68  11.21  11.48 2022-06-22
12  11.50  11.58  11.25  11.56 2022-06-23
13  11.65  12.12  11.57  12.01 2022-06-24
14  12.12  12.18  11.90  12.04 2022-06-27
15  12.14  12.44  11.80  11.81 2022-06-28
16  11.74  11.76  11.38  11.52 2022-06-29
17  11.24  11.36  10.93  11.13 2022-06-30
18  11.10  11.50  10.99  11.32 2022-07-01
```

###### d-m-YYYY **string** format:

Add `.dt.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y')` to you command:

```
candleData['time'] = (pd.to_datetime(pd.json_normalize(candleData['time']))
                        .dt.strftime('%-d-%-m-%Y')
                        )
```

output:

```
     open   high    low  close       time
0   13.74  13.74  13.38  13.46   6-6-2022
1   13.26  13.77  13.19  13.74   7-6-2022
2   13.63  13.85  13.44  13.53   8-6-2022
3   13.51  13.59  13.28  13.28   9-6-2022
4   13.00  13.21  12.63  12.75  10-6-2022
5   12.30  12.38  11.74  11.81  13-6-2022
6   11.99  12.42  11.91  12.20  14-6-2022
7   12.22  12.42  12.00  12.27  15-6-2022
8   11.80  11.91  11.12  11.25  16-6-2022
9   11.24  11.44  10.90  11.23  17-6-2022
10  11.55  11.66  11.35  11.46  21-6-2022
11  11.26  11.68  11.21  11.48  22-6-2022
12  11.50  11.58  11.25  11.56  23-6-2022
13  11.65  12.12  11.57  12.01  24-6-2022
14  12.12  12.18  11.90  12.04  27-6-2022
15  12.14  12.44  11.80  11.81  28-6-2022
16  11.74  11.76  11.38  11.52  29-6-2022
17  11.24  11.36  10.93  11.13  30-6-2022
18  11.10  11.50  10.99  11.32   1-7-2022
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

`candleData.time.apply(lambda x: f"{x['day']}-{x['month']}-{x['year']}")`